# How to run WordCountTopology from storm-starter in Intellij

Tags: python, intellij-idea, apache-storm

I work with Storm for a while already, but want to get started with development. As suggested, I am using IntelliJ (up to now, I was using Eclipse and did only write topologies against Java API).

I was also looking at
https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/examples/storm-starter#intellij-idea

This documentation is not complete. I was not able to run anything in Intellij first. I could figure out, that I need to remove the scope of storm-core dependency (in storm-starter pom.xml). (found here: [storm-starter with intellij idea,maven project could not find class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30724424/storm-starter-with-intellij-idea-maven-project-could-not-find-class))

After that I was able to build the project. I can also run `ExclamationTopology` with no problems within IntelliJ. However, `WordCountTopology` fails.

First I got the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: backtype.storm.multilang.NoOutputException: Pipe to subprocess seems to be broken! No output read.
>   Serializer Exception:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "splitsentence.py", line 16, in 
>       import storm
>   ImportError: No module named storm

**Update: installing `python-storm` is not required to make it work**

<s>I was able to resolve it via: apt-get install python-storm (from StackOverflow)</s>

However, I don't speak Python and was wondering what the problem is and why I could resolve it like this. Just want to get deeper into it. Maybe someone can explain.

Unfortunately, I am getting a different error now:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: backtype.storm.multilang.NoOutputException: Pipe to subprocess seems to be broken! No output read.
>   Serializer Exception:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "splitsentence.py", line 18, in 
>       class SplitSentenceBolt(storm.BasicBolt):
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BasicBolt'

I did not find any solution on the Internet. Asking at `dev@storm.apache.org` did not help either. I go the following suggestion:

> I think that it was always assumed that topology would always be invoked through storm-command line. Thus working directory would be ${STORM-INSTALLATION}/bin/storm Since storm.py is in the this directory, splitSentence.py would be able to find storm modules. Can you set the working directory to a path, where storm.py is present and then try. If it works, we can add it later to the documentation

However, chancing the working directory did not solve the problem.

And as I am not familiar with Python and as I am new to IntelliJ, I am stuck now. Because `ExclamationTopology` runs, I guess my basic setup is correct.

What do I do wrong? It is possible at all to run `WordcountTopology` in `LocalCluster` in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, AFAIK you can't run multilang feature with LocalCluster without having packaged file.

ShellProcess relies on codeDir of TopologyContext, which is used by supervisor.
Workers are serialized to stormcode.ser, but multilang files should extracted to outside of serialized file so that python/ruby/node/etc can load it.

Accomplishing this with distribute mode is easy because there's always user submitted jar, and supervisor can know it is what user submitted.

But accomplishing this with local mode is not easy cause supervisor cannot know user submitted jar, and users can run topology to local mode without packaging.

So, Supervisor in local mode finds resource directory ("resources") from each jars (which ends with "jar") in classpath, and copy first occurrence to codeDir.

`storm jar` places user topology jar to the first of classpath, so it can be run without issue.

So normally, it's natural for ShellProcess to not find "splitsentence.py". Maybe your working directory or PYTHONPATH did the trick.

Comment: Setting PYTHONPATH does the trick! `SplitSentence pythonSplit = new SplitSentence();
    Map env = new HashMap();
    env.put("PYTHONPATH", "/home/mjsax/workspace_storm/storm/storm-multilang/python/src/main/resources/resources/");
    pythonSplit.setEnv(env);
    builder.setBolt("split",pythonSplit, 8).shuffleGrouping("spout");`

Comment: Yes, in case of not finding multilang implementations of storm-starter, you can add these to PYTHONPATH, too.

Comment: It is no contained in storm starter. And not each version of `storm.py` works. The code contains 5 files with 3 different version. Could not figure out why there are different version though. Do you know?

Comment: bin/storm.py is launcher / shell script for Storm components. (storm-dist/binary/target/apache-storm-0.11.0-SNAPSHOT/bin/storm.py is copied version)

Comment: storm-multilang/python/src/main/resources/resources/storm.py is actual multilang source code for python. storm-core copies it to target/test-classes cause multilang test needs this. (storm-core/target/test-classes/resources/storm.py) storm-multilang/python/target/classes/resources/storm.py is just a build result ready for packaging to jar.

Comment: Yes, agreed. But if we change its name we will break backward compatibility (changing module name) so it is not an easy issue.

Comment: Thanks. This is regular maven build process. That this is the reason for multiple copies of the same file was clear to me. Backward compatibility -- I see. Makes sens. Maybe it should be documented somewhere... ;)

Comment: @Matthias J. Sax can you please provide some help regrading your piece of code in the comment above?  pythonSplit does not have setEnv ! So this line of code pythonSplit.setEnv(env);  does not work? Any chance you can provide more of the above code?

Comment: `SplitSentence` extends `ShellBolt` and inherits `setEnv` from it: https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/4ecae60ad76ee8729c819aa30b048f59a54c1ff3/storm-core/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/task/ShellBolt.java Thus, is should be there...

Comment: In Storm `1.x` package got restructured, thus, you can find `python.py` in `storm-multilang/python/src/main/resources/resources` now.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with a similar issue, not with the sample topology, but with my own using a Python bolt.

Also experienced the "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BasicBolt'" exception - in local mode and when submitting to the cluster.

There are very few resources on this, I found your question and little else discussing this issue.

In case someone else has the same problem:
Make sure you include the correct Maven "multilang-python" dependency in your pom file. This will package the correct run time dependencies into the JAR file needed to run your topology.

Comment: excuse me i'm facing same problem but couldn't solve it , how can i know the correct maven i should use it ?

Comment: If I recall correctly, you must just match the version numbers on the multilang-python dependency to the main storm dependency

Answer (score 0):

I managed to run it on my virtualbox, storm version 1.2.2:

just download https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/storm-multilang/python/src/main/resources/resources/storm.py and put it into any folder you want, for example: /apache-storm-1.2.2/examples/storm-starter/multilang/resources/ , and then change the main function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    SplitSentence pythonSplit = new SplitSentence();
    Map env = new HashMap();
    env.put("PYTHONPATH", "/apache-storm-1.2.2/examples/storm-starter/multilang/resources/");
    pythonSplit.setEnv(env);

    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

    builder.setSpout("spout", new RandomSentenceSpout(), 5);

    builder.setBolt("split",pythonSplit, 8).shuffleGrouping("spout");
    builder.setBolt("count", new WordCount(), 12).fieldsGrouping("split", new Fields("word"));

    Config conf = new Config();
    conf.setDebug(true);

    if (args != null && args.length > 0) {
      conf.setNumWorkers(3);

      StormSubmitter.submitTopologyWithProgressBar(args[0], conf, builder.createTopology());
    }
    else {
      conf.setMaxTaskParallelism(3);

      LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
      cluster.submitTopology("word-count", conf, builder.createTopology());

      Thread.sleep(600000);

      cluster.shutdown();
    }
  }
```

the full instructions can be found on my blog which includes other issues encountered when running it in Local Mode and Local Cluster mode: https://lyhistory.com/storm/