# How do I configure Apache Storm to find Python when running a multilang topology?

Tags: java, python, apache-storm

I'm trying to run the example `WordCount` topology from the Storm [repo](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/examples/storm-starter/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/starter/WordCountTopology.java).

I have a new Storm project created, and Storm added as a dependency via Maven. I'm able to successfully run the `ExclamationTopology`, so Storm in general is working. I have python installed:

```
zachary:~ zachary$ python --version

Python 2.7.6

zachary:~ zachary$ which python

/usr/bin/python
```

I've added the Python script to the `multilang/resources` directory in my new project. I've tried adding both the `multilang` and `resources`, and either/or, as source paths to my project, but I am still always getting this error:

```
6239 [Thread-20-split] ERROR b.s.d.executor - 

java.lang.RuntimeException: Error when launching multilang subprocess



at backtype.storm.utils.ShellProcess.launch(ShellProcess.java:68) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]

at backtype.storm.task.ShellBolt.prepare(ShellBolt.java:117) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]

at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5694$fn__5707.invoke(executor.clj:757) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]

at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__545.invoke(util.clj:477) [storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]

at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_45]

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python" (in directory "/var/folders/rr/tb1q5lv93sldld20pln730kr0000gn/T/ad72dd44-af9b-4849-8400-b1a2596e6f37/supervisor/stormdist/word-count-1-1456069567/resources"): error=2, No such file or directory

at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048) ~[?:1.8.0_45]

at backtype.storm.utils.ShellProcess.launch(ShellProcess.java:61) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]

... 5 more

Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory

at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_45]

at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:248) ~[?:1.8.0_45]

at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134) ~[?:1.8.0_45]

at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029) ~[?:1.8.0_45]

at backtype.storm.utils.ShellProcess.launch(ShellProcess.java:61) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]

... 5 more
```

I've searched and this seems to be a common error, relating to adding `multilang/resources` as a source path in the project, but I have done this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31985819/how-to-run-wordcounttopology-from-storm-starter-in-intellij

Comment: Thank you for the link. I'm currently trying to play with setting the `env` like you did in that thread. Can you illuminate why I'm getting a `method setEnv(Map) is undefined for the type WordCountTopology.SplitSentence`? My `SplitSentence` extends `ShellBolt`, and I see `setEnv` in the Github [code](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/a4f9f8bc5b4ca85de487a0a868e519ddcb94e852/storm-core/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/task/ShellBolt.java), but not in these [docs](https://storm.apache.org/apidocs/backtype/storm/task/ShellBolt.html). Misunderstanding of mine regarding the Storm code setup?

Comment: No idea why `setEnv(Map)`  is "undefined"... It should be there.

Comment: Yeah, that is where I'm focused now and it's very weird. I believe [This](https://github.com/apache/storm/pull/575) is the PR where `setEnv` was introduced, in July. `0.10.0` was released since then, and my `pom.xml` requests version `0.10.0` with scope `compile`. Similarly, in my project, I cannot access `setEnv` on an instance of `ShellSpout`.

Comment: Actually, is it possible it didn't make it into the 0.10.0 release? If the beta for 0.10.0 was in June, but the PR for `setEnv` was in July, then it makes sense it would have missed the 0.10.0 release, right? And since my project is relying on the maven dependency, I would have to build and include Storm myself to be able to use `setEnv`?

Comment: I just had a look into the code: https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/storm/apache-storm-0.10.0/apache-storm-0.10.0-src.zip You are right, `setEnv` is not part of 0.10.0... No idea how you can fix your problem. (I doubt that you want to use current master... do you?)

Comment: Well, if I can find a way to have multilang working locally without requiring the setting of `PYTHONPATH`, that would work great too. Alternatively, would it be that crazy to clone `storm`, `maven install`, and then just add the jars myself instead of using a maven dependency? It seems thats described in the [docs](http://storm.apache.org/documentation/Creating-a-new-Storm-project.html) too. But you've scared me with your question. : )